# Are there any benefits to defining the type when it comes to PHP variables

Tags: php, variables, types

I've never really bothered to predefine variables or for that matter, defined what type of variable it is. I'm trying to improve my code by doing these things.

I've read that it's better practice to predefine PHP variables but can't find much information on the benefits when it comes to defining a type.

I'm interested to know if there are any speed benefits and hear what other people have to say on the subject.

Comment: nope no benefits at all since php is loosely typed

Comment: Without predefined variable, it shows warning (it depends on php.ini settings) so it is best practice to define it before. No speed benefits.

Comment: The one benefit I see in per-defining a variable is, if you define some variable inside a conditional block, you can live without `if (isset ...` code when you want to use the variable outside the condition.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit is purely in readability.

In theory, you could do

```
$var = 42;
$var = "Hello World!";
$var = false;
```

And it would be fine. However, that doesn't make sense in most applications, nor is it very readable (spread those lines around a 1000 line page, and you'll understand what I'm saying).

Predefining a variable gives you a clear understanding of what the variable holds, and what its purpose is.

It should be used in conjunction with

- Proper variable name
- Proper variable scope

Comment: Ok, I can see the benefit here. So why does PHP have the function `settype`, if it doesn't really matter anyway?

Comment: @PapaSmurf: It allows you to type cast during run time. Much like `define()` vs `const`. It helps when you need to convert unconventional things like `"5bar"` to int for example, which would become `5`.

Answer (score 0):

For code readability it is advisable to define your variables outside of the scope that uses them. PHP allows you to create variables inside a block such as an if statement or loop and then use that variable outside that block scope. This is very confusing when you try to edit someone else's code.

So for the sake of easy refactoring and code readability you should define your variables outside of block statements that use them.

As for defining types, PHP is not a strongly typed language. About the best you can do is use typing hinting and define object types in your function declarations.